# Developing a game

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game using libgdx framework. I want to raise a dialogue when I pause the game, and on that dialogue I want to use a resume button. I know that I should use `pause()` and `resume()` methods, but I'm not able to understand what I should write in those methods.

Any help would be apprechiated.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused, the pause and resume states indicated in your call back functions have nothing to do with your game or whether the game is 'Playing'. These calls are used when the OS decides to suspend the application for some reason.

A quick look at the android developers documentation will help you with these 'lifetime' issues - on the other hand you need to implement your own pause and resume logic in the game in some way.

Comment: ,thank you for your response. I have a logic, but i cant able to understand where to write it. can you help me on this.

Comment: I suggest you open another question including bits of the code you already have to implement this interface so we can see how you logic works

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this problem is to make an enum for your game state (PLAY, PAUSE). In your main game loop you can use an if else statement. if(GameState == PLAY) update all gameplay stuff. if(GameState == PAUSE) update your menu manager.

Typically in game architecture one should use states for these types of problems. Another rule of game architecture is to have all game play entities behave in relation to elapsedTime. That way, that rate of game play is always the same no matter what device the game is being played on. I use seconds as a decimal in all of my games so all motion is in meters per second. That way I can plug in real physics equations so I'm not chasing around crazy numbers all the time trying to get things to work.

A quick fix for a pause in this case would be to just set your elapsed seconds to zero when the game is in pause state. This is a hack! proving that using states is almost always the best idea, especially with manager classes such as a game class.

You may even consider creating a GameState class that is responsible for transitions between states. This will be handy for playing sounds and starting animations such as the menu moving down from the top of the screen, in this time the game is in neither PAUSE nor PLAY; food for thought.

Getting into mobile games, having a TOMBSTONE and REVIVE transition states would be perfect for temporarily caching the game into storage while the device handles other applications.